# Choose which duplicate row to delete?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm using this to delete duplicate records from a MySql/MariaDB table based on three columns being the same.

```
DELETE a FROM stest as a, stest as b
WHERE
      (a.facility_id=b.facility_id OR a.facility_id IS NULL AND b.facility_id IS NULL)
  AND (a.inspection_date=b.inspection_date OR a.inspection_date IS NULL AND b.inspection_date IS NULL)
  AND (a.deficiency_tag=b.deficiency_tag OR a.deficiency_tag IS NULL AND b.deficiency_tag IS NULL)
  AND a.recno < b.recno;
```

What I'd like to do is, where there are duplicate records, keep the one with the largest length(inspection_text) column.  (In all likelihood, the inspection_text columns will be identical, but if they're not, I want to delete the smaller ones)

Can someone give me an idea of how I might modify the above statement to add this condition?

I'm also curious as to how the DELETE works, but if I change "DELETE a" to "SELECT a.*"  It doesn't show the rows to be deleted but all rows in the table?

Comment: `if I change "DELETE a" to "SELECT a.*" It doesn't show the rows to be deleted but all rows in the table?` - Your query is *not* doing what you think it's doing.  **`AND` takes precedence over `OR`**.  You need to use another set of parenthesis:  ex -
 `WHERE (a.facility_id=b.facility_id OR (a.facility_id IS NULL AND b.facility_id IS NULL))`.  **All of the other `WHERE` clauses need the same update.**  The results you're seeing in the `SELECT` statement are 100% correct.

Comment: Also, please stop using implicit `JOIN` syntax.  This was replaced with ANSI-**92** (over **25 years ago**).

Comment: assign a user variable to each group which represents the row number of each group ordered by your facility, inspection, deficiency then length desc.  then delete where the rowNumber > 1

Answer (score 1):

for obtain the the values  you want to delete you could use  and inner join with the value witg max_len of inspection_text
for the dupliceted  row  and delete the row with lenght <> to max_len

```
   delete from  stest 
   inner join ( 

       select  facility_id, deficiency_tag, inspection_date , max(length( inspection_text)) as  max_len from stest
       where ( facility_id, deficiency_tag, inspection_date ) in ( 

       select facility_id, deficiency_tag, inspection_date 
       from stest
       group by facility_id, deficiency_tag, inspection_date
       having count(*) > 1 
       ) 
       group by  facility_id, deficiency_tag, inspection_date
   ) t  on stest.facility_id = t.facility_id 
              and stest.deficiency_tag = t.deficiency_tag
                and stest.inspection_date = t.inspection_date
                  and length( stest.inspection_text) <> t.max_len
```

and this don't use tuple for join

```
   delete from  stest 
   inner join ( 
       select  
            facility_id
          , deficiency_tag
          , inspection_date 
          , max( length( inspection_text) ) as  max_len 
       from stest
       innert join ( 
          select 
              facility_id
            , deficiency_tag
            , inspection_date 
         from stest
         group by facility_id, deficiency_tag, inspection_date
         having count(*) > 1 
       ) t2 on stest.facility_id = t2.facility_id and stest.deficiency_tag = t2.deficiency_tag and stest.inspection_date = t2.inspection_date
       group by  facility_id, deficiency_tag, inspection_date
   ) t  on stest.facility_id = t.facility_id 
              and stest.deficiency_tag = t.deficiency_tag
                and stest.inspection_date = t.inspection_date
```

same version without inner join  but where  ..

```
   delete from  stest ,  ( 
       select  
            facility_id
          , deficiency_tag
          , inspection_date 
          , max( length( inspection_text) ) as  my_max_len 
       from stest, ( 
          select 
              facility_id
            , deficiency_tag
            , inspection_date 
         from stest
         group by facility_id, deficiency_tag, inspection_date
         having count(*) > 1 
       ) t2 where  stest.facility_id = t2.facility_id and stest.deficiency_tag = t2.deficiency_tag and stest.inspection_date = t2.inspection_date
       group by  facility_id, deficiency_tag, inspection_date
   ) t  where  stest.facility_id = t.facility_id 
              and stest.deficiency_tag = t.deficiency_tag
                and stest.inspection_date = t.inspection_date
                    and length( stest.inspection_text) <> t.my_max_len
```

Comment: I'm getting an error in the above statement (minus the one syntax error I corrected)..

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'inner join ( 
       select  facility_id, deficiency_tag, inspection_date , max' at line 2

Comment: I corrected the table name.. still get that error.  I was able to execute the statement inside the inner join() and it works.  I'm unable to see where the error is.. any ideas?

Comment: I'm using 5.5.52-MariaDB  if this makes a difference.... perhaps this version does not support inner join?

Comment: just a space between stest.inspection_text  ..answer  updated .  (space removed)

Comment: for mariadb 5.5.52 i don't know  ..release date   2016-09-13

Comment: I'm at a loss.  I can't find where inner join may not be supported in 5.5, but it's acting like it doesn't recognize that command... ??

Comment: i have add a new version that don't use tuple . could be that problem is related  to this feature  .. any way inner  join can easly changed in where  ...the on condition is essentially  the where  ..

Comment: I get the same error on the second version too.  It looks like my version of MariaDB may not support inner join or not have it enabled?

Comment: answer  update with where and not inner join  .. just for test try also use my_max_len  instead of max_len ..  (changhe the name for the alias )

Comment: tried the last/third one and still getting an error - this must be something obvious neither one of us is noticing.. #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '( select facility_id , deficiency_tag ' at line 1 –